# Javascript regular expression syntax issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression in JavaScript that works in every browser I've tested except for mobile safari on ios. It also gives a red semicolon in Visual Studio Code.

```
var wordMarkup_regexp = /[\w']+/igu;
```

I have tried surrounding the regex with double quotes and at that point it no longer works anywhere.

How to fix this syntax?

Comment: why do you want to put regex in double quotes? you want to  check for double quotes in your regex?

Comment: It's very likely because of the `u` (unicode) flag [which is new.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)  What version of Safari are you testing on?

Comment: please provide invalid regex as well

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk The regex is in the question.

Comment: I removed the unicode flag and that expression no longer breaks my code on mobile Safari 9. Thanks Scott and everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
var wordMarkup_regexp = new RegExp("[\w']+", 'igu');
```

Comment: This will still throw an error on runtime if the `u` flag is not supported